# android.widget.RadioGroup cannot be cast to android.widget.RadioButton

Tags: java, android, loops, radio-button, onclicklistener

I've created pragmatically 5 radio groups with 4 radio buttons each. When I am trying to use `checkedRadioButton` the emulator crushes? The error is: `android.widget.RadioGroup cannot be cast to android.widget.RadioButton`. Where am I wrong?

Here is my code:

```
    radioGroup = new RadioGroup[5];
    answer = new RadioButton[4];
    int i = 0;
    for (Question qn : questions) {
        radioGroup[i] = new RadioGroup(this);
        radioGroup[i].setId(i);
        int j = 0;
        for (Answer an : answers) {
            if (qn.getID() == an.getQuestion_id_answer()) {
                answer[j] = new RadioButton(this);
                answer[j].setText(an.getAnswer());
                answer[j].setId(j);
                radioGroup[i].addView(answer[j]);

                answer[j].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int checkedRadioButtonId = v.getId();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checkbox" + checkedRadioButtonId + " checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedRadioButtonId);
                    }
                });
                j++;
            }
        }
        linearLayout.addView(radioGroup[i]);
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: from the error it seems pretty obvious that you are casting radio group in radio button or vice versa,

Comment: answer[j] = new RadioButton(this);
                answer[j].setText(an.getAnswer());
                answer[j].setId(j);
                radioGroup[i].addView(answer[j]);

Comment: Ok, but what do i need to change to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the id for the `RadioGroup` as well as the `RadioButton` views programmatically by

```
radioGroup[i].setId(i);
```

respectively

```
answer[j].setId(j);
```

Because some values of the i's can also be values for the j's (e.g. i=j=0), you sometimes assign the same id twice.

The method `findViewById()` will return any `View` with matching id, the returned `View` is only after that cast to the appropriate class.

Now accidentally in the line

```
RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedRadioButtonId);
```

the `RadioGroup` with the requested id '`checkedRadioButtonId`' is found first.  This causes the crash.

To solve the problem, use the tag attribute, for example

`radioGroup[i].setTag("rg" + i);` and `answer[j].setTag("rb" + j);`

Then you can get the individual `View` with tag "xyz" by writing

```
RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewWithTag("xyz");
```

Comment: Yes, you are perfectly right. But when i try to set the id of the radio group `radioGroup[i].setId("rg" + i);` it says: `setId(int) in View cannot be applied to java.lang.String`

Comment: Ok, I never tried to do it programmatically, I just use xml and there I can write android:id="some_name". Of course, the "id" here must be the "R.id.whatever" which is an int value :(. I'll edit my answer - thanks

Comment: I cannot use XML because i need to generate 80 radio groups and i don't want to write them manually.

Comment: @Alex M. - yeah - I did not want you to ;) Please see my edited answer.

Comment: If I set tag with `"rb"+j`, then how will I get that by `findViewWithTag("rb" +j)`, there is no `j` in `onCheckedChanged`

Comment: I have posted a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38216284/android-cannot-cast-android-widget-radiogroup-to-android-widget-radiobutton), have a look.