# Android - cannot cast android.widget.RadioGroup to android.widget.RadioButton

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33610586/android-widget-radiogroup-cannot-be-cast-to-android-widget-radiobutton) but this question is little bit different.

I am creating 15 RadioGroups and 4 radio buttons inside each group using for loop.

```
for(int i=0; i<15; i++) {
      RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(getActivity());
      radioGroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
      radioGroup.setLayoutParams(lp);
      radioGroup.setId(i+1);

      for(int j=0; j<4; j++) {
            RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(getActivity());
            radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
        }

      radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(radioListener);

}
```

And this is radio listener code:

```
final RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener radioListener = new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton radio = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(checkedId);
            String selectedValue = radio.getText().toString();

        }
    };
```

The above code is responsible for the exception. According to Android developers, `checkedId` is

> the unique identifier of the newly checked radio button

The problem with this code is that it works sometimes and doesn't works other times. There are a total of 15 radiogroups so if I select radiobuttons from 2nd to 15th group, it will show no error and everything will execute perfectly but when I select the 1st radio button of the very first radio group, it throws the exception - cannot cast `android.widget.radiogroup` to `android.widget.radiobutton`

Comment: But here you are not assigning id to the radio buttons 

`for(int j=0; j<4; j++) {
            RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(getActivity());
            radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
        }` 

once specify id to the radio buttons then try to do something.

Comment: @NigamPatro Yeah thanks, instead of doing `radioButton.setId(j)`, I did `radioButton.setId(j+100)` so it doesn't create assign the same ids to both radiogroups and radiobuttons.

Comment: Why don't you look for button inside `radioGroup` instead of `rootView`:

`RadioButton radio = (RadioButton) = radioGroup.findViewById(checkedId);`

Comment: Chinmay Sarupria - @R. Zagórski is right, you will get a unique id only within the RadioGroup because you set the id values to 100, 101, 102 and 103 for each i between  0 and 14. id values do not have to be unique, and rootView.findViewById() simply returns the first View with the given id. The exception must have occurred because you gave the same id value to a RadioGroup and a RadioButton and `findViewById()` ran into the RadioGroup first.